# get exit code 1 when run flutter project

Tags: flutter, gradle, build

when i run flutter project i get this error .

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Problems reading data from Binary store in 
C:\Users\Mohammad\AppData\Local\Temp\gradle3241964870133562548.bin offset 235082 exists? true

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log 
output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 8s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

i restart my pc and after clean temp directory , also i run `flutter clean` but this error yet exist please help me my build.gradle file is

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com/"}
}

dependencies {

    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
   }
 }
```